# Why does this code always return 'True' even if no IPv6? Is it wrong?

Tags: .net, powershell, udp

Not a powershell expert but doing something to check for IPv6 connectivity as part of a small project for Windows 10. This (code below) is what I'm using, i'd like to stay with it if possible because its fast and does not involve a web site somewhere to return the public view IPv6 address. The remote IPv6 address used (2001:4860:4860::8888) is the Google public IPv6 DNS. I got the idea from some code in which the Google Ipv6 DNS server is used to check for global Ipv6 connectivity in Chrome from this > https://codereview.chromium.org/141023002 <

```
$Saddrf   = [System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily]::InterNetworkV6;
$Stypeg   = [System.Net.Sockets.SocketType]::Dgram ;
$Ptypeg   = [System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType]::UDP ;
$Sockg    = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.Socket($Saddrf, $Stypeg, $Ptypeg);
$Sockg.Connect('2001:4860:4860::8888', 53); $cnx = $Sockg.Connected;
write $cnx
```

The problem with it is that even with the IPv6 disabled on the interface adapter and Teredo disabled it still returns 'True' (that its connected) when it should not be connected. I want it to return 'False' when there is no IPv6 enabled on the interface adapter or IPv6 is blocked at firewall or via something else. What am I doing wrong with this?

Comment: A cursory glance at the chromium code snippet suggests to me that it actually sends a DNS packet to the Google public DNS resolver, returning true only when it receives a response.  The code above only creates a udp6 socket and stops there.

Comment: That's what I thought too at first but reading the link from where I got the idea says "(Note that no packets are actually sent as a result of the checks; UDP
doesn't need to send any packets to connect, and the HostResolverImpl
doesn't send any data over the socket explicitly.)"

Comment: From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.connected): `If you call Connect on a User Datagram Protocol (UDP) socket, the Connected property always returns true; however, this action does not change the inherent connectionless nature of UDP.`

Comment: Ahhh HA! so its always going to return true if its actually connected or not if its UDP. Well, I guess that answers that.

Answer (score 3):

UDP protocol is connectionless. So, "connected" state has no practical meaning for it, unlike TCP (and you receive just hardcoded stub value, I'm suspecting). Then, you can try to switch to TCP version of DNS request from very beginning (despite RFC recommends to use TCP DNS only if the UDP response contains "truncated" flag).

Comment: Didn't think about that, but maybe. I wonder though how it works in the Chrome code correctly but when the same thing is created in Powershell it fails.

Comment: +1; @John: The issue has nothing to with PowerShell per; it's how the `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` .NET class is designed: ["If you call Connect on a User Datagram Protocol (UDP) socket, the Connected property always returns `true`; however, this action does not change the inherent connectionless nature of UDP."](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.connected) The word "action" may be confusing; what they mean is that even though the property claims a state of being connected, the concept of  a connection doesn't really apply to the connectionless UDP protocol.

Answer (score 2):

With another look at the [chromium code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/57.0.2987.98/net/dns/host_resolver_impl.cc#220) we can see what it's doing.

TL;DR, it checks whether the machine actually has a valid non-local, non-tunneled, ipv6 address assigned.

The critical function (or method, it's C++) is [bool IsGloballyReachable()](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/57.0.2987.98/net/dns/host_resolver_impl.cc#220)

It starts with some boiler plate with the function header, a tracing function, and the creation of a UDP socket pointer

```
// Attempts to connect a UDP socket to |dest|:53.
bool IsGloballyReachable(const IPAddress& dest,
             const NetLogWithSource& net_log) {
  // TODO(eroman): Remove ScopedTracker below once crbug.com/455942 is fixed.
  tracked_objects::ScopedTracker tracking_profile_1(
  FROM_HERE_WITH_EXPLICIT_FUNCTION("455942 IsGloballyReachable")
  );

  std::unique_ptr<DatagramClientSocket> socket(
    ClientSocketFactory::GetDefaultFactory()->CreateDatagramClientSocket(
      DatagramSocket::DEFAULT_BIND, 
      RandIntCallback(), 
      net_log.net_log(),
      net_log.source()
    )
  );
```

Then comes the first test: can we *connect* to the given address?

```
  int rv = socket->Connect(IPEndPoint(dest, 53));
  if (rv != OK)
      return false;
```

If this fails, that's what we return.

This is where the powershell code stops

But we aren't done yet...

The next test: Can we get the local address for the socket?

```
  IPEndPoint endpoint;
  rv = socket->GetLocalAddress(&endpoint);
  if (rv != OK)
      return false;
```

If that works, we start checking the actual address,

```
  DCHECK_EQ(ADDRESS_FAMILY_IPV6, endpoint.GetFamily());
  const IPAddress& address = endpoint.address();
```

We first eliminate link_local addresses:

```
  bool is_link_local =
  (address.bytes()[0] == 0xFE) && ((address.bytes()[1] & 0xC0) == 0x80);
  if (is_link_local)
      return false;
```

And we eliminate addresses with a teredo prefix

```
  const uint8_t kTeredoPrefix[] = {0x20, 0x01, 0, 0};
  if (IPAddressStartsWith(address, kTeredoPrefix))
      return false;
```

Anything else is assumed to be a valid local ipv6 address in the global address space:

```
  return true;
}
```

Does this actually test global connectivity?  No.  As you aren't actually sending any packets around this will not see if there's any firewall that might block your traffic.  But it validates that at least one network interface has a valid non-local ipv6 address.

To replicate this test you would need to check that the network interface you *connect* through is actually an ipv6 address.

Comment: Ahh, I see now. I mistook it as actually checking for Ipv6 global connectivity when what its really doing is basically checking to see if a global Ipv6 address is available.

Comment: Good summary. I should add that as the tl;dr